# titandb gremlin-server running out of memory how to set #jsr223.groovy.engine.keep.globals

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm running several instances of titandb / gremlin-server.sh but it keeps running out of memory under high load. How and where do I set the property mentioned in th the docs?

I would like to set #jsr223.groovy.engine.keep.globals to phantom.

Thanks

> Cache Management
>
> If Gremlin Server processes a large number of unique scripts, the
>   cache will grow beyond the memory available to Gremlin Server and an
>   OutOfMemoryError will loom. Script parameterization goes a long way to
>   solving this problem and running out of memory should not be an issue
>   for those cases. If it is a problem or if there is no script
>   parameterization due to a given use case (perhaps using with use of
>   sessions), it is possible to better control the nature of the script
>   cache from the client side, by issuing scripts with a parameter to
>   help define how the garbage collector should treat the references.
>
> The parameter is called #jsr223.groovy.engine.keep.globals and has
>   four options:
>
> hard - available in the cache for the life of the JVM (default when
>   not specified).
>
> soft - retained until memory is "low" and should be reclaimed before
>   an OutOfMemoryError is thrown.
>
> weak - garbage collected even when memory is abundant.
>
> phantom - removed immediately after being evaluated by the
>   ScriptEngine.
>
> By specifying an option other than hard, an OutOfMemoryError in
>   Gremlin Server should be avoided. Of course, this approach will come
>   with the downside that compiled scripts could be garbage collected and
>   thus removed from the cache, forcing Gremlin Server to recompile
>   later.

Comment: Titan calls ./scripts/empty-sample.groovy is this where I should set it?

Answer (score 0):

It is a per request feature:

> it is possible to better control the nature of the script cache from the client side, by issuing scripts with a parameter to help define how the garbage collector should treat the references.

You must construct your request with a parameter called `#jsr223.groovy.engine.keep.globals` and it should have a value of `phantom` in your case.

For REST I think you would do:

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"gremlin\":\"100-x\", \"bindings\":{\"x\":1, \"#jsr223.groovy.engine.keep.globals\":\"phantom\"}}" "http://localhost:8182"
```

Comment: Thanks stephen. I just need to work out how to pass this using gremlin-php and sockets now.